# AST2500 Evaulation Board Build Image

Tags: openbmc

Our final image is lacking OpenBMC features such as SSH, Web GUI, and IPMI

We have a AST2500 evaluation board.
We are using recommended build environment and setting:
 export TEMPLATECONF=meta-evb/meta-evb-aspeed/meta-evb-ast2500/conf
We are using bitbake to build phosphor image:

. oe-init-build-env
bitbake obmc-phosphor-image

The final image is in:
openbmc/build/tmp/deploy/images/evb-ast2500

We put the following image (about 7.5 MB) in our TFTP server
 fitImage-aspeed-image-initramfs-evb-ast2500--5.3.1+git0+3ad520f93d-r0-evb-ast2500-20191030145446.bin -> evb.bin

and then from uboot we can:
 dhcp evb.bin
 bootm

System boots and we can log in as:
root
0penBmc

But we only get a minimal OS.
There are no OpenBmc features (such as ssh, web server, ipmi stack, etc) in this final image
What are we doing wrong?

We also get the following tar file:
 obmc-phosphor-image-evb-ast2500-20191030145446.rootfs.tar.gz

When we open the tar file, all these services are in /usr/bin of the tar file.
But they are not in the /usr/bin file we loaded to AST2500 evaluation board.

There are no error messages.
The sshd daemon and other services are just not there.

Thanks

Comment: We add the following line to b uild/conf/local.conf to create *.mtd build file         
  "require conf/machine/include/obmc-bsp-common.inc". then we used the QEMU and used *.mtd file to start the simulator. It worked fine and /usr/bin has all the phosphor services and ssh. So we try to load *.mtd file to AST2500 evaluation board from UBoot (dhcp evb.mtd ; bootm 83080000) it finds the FIT image and start loading the Kernel. But it hangs after that. This is the output from the COM Port:

Comment: ast# bootm 83080000
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 83080000 ...
   Using 'conf@aspeed-ast2500-evb.dtb' configuration
   Trying 'kernel@1' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x8308012c
     Data Size:    2732016 Bytes = 2.6 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x80001000
     Entry Point:  0x80001000
     Hash algo:    sha256
     Hash value:   
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha256+ OK

Comment: ## Loading ramdisk from FIT Image at 83080000 ...
   Using 'conf@aspeed-ast2500-evb.dtb' configuration
   Trying 'ramdisk@1' ramdisk subimage
     Description:  obmc-phosphor-initramfs
     Type:         RAMDisk Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x8332208c
     Data Size:    1115892 Bytes = 1.1 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: unavailable
     Entry Point:  unavailable
     Hash algo:    sha256
     Hash value:   
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha256+ OK

Comment: ## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 83080000 ...
   Using 'conf@aspeed-ast2500-evb.dtb' configuration
   Trying 'fdt@aspeed-ast2500-evb.dtb' fdt subimage
     Description:  Flattened Device Tree blob
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x8331b230
     Data Size:    28048 Bytes = 27.4 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha256
     Hash value:   
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha256+ OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x8331b230

Comment: Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Ramdisk to bc24f000, end bc35f6f4 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to bc245000, end bc24ed8f ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Answer (score 3):

It was an issue that the evb-ast2500 was building a minimal image.

But check the latest master's README, and see below

> For evb-ast2500, please use the below command to specify the machine config, because the machine in meta-aspeed layer is in a BSP layer and does not build the openbmc image.
>
> `TEMPLATECONF=meta-evb/meta-evb-aspeed/meta-evb-ast2500/conf . openbmc-env`

With the master branch and the above command, you should be able to build the openbmc image instead of a minimal image.