# Looking for instructions for how to build OpenBMC for AST2600

Tags: build, openbmc

I am trying to build OpenBMC for AST2600.

I have been able to successfully follow the steps described in [AST2500 Evaulation Board Build Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645796/ast2500-evaulation-board-build-image), to build AST2500 OpenBMC image. However, looks like additional work needed to modify content downloaded via 'git clone git@github.com:openbmc/openbmc.git' in order to enable successful AST2600 OpenBMC build. I am wondering if anyone has already done this.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

The witherspoon-tacama machine builds for the AST2600. You could use this machine as a reference.

https://github.com/openbmc/meta-ibm/blob/master/conf/machine/witherspoon-tacoma.conf

Answer (score 1):

Check here: https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc#openbmc

and also the wiki: https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/wiki

```
git clone git@github.com:openbmc/openbmc.git
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc.git
```

then

```
cd openbmc
```

then

```
source setup witherspoon-tacoma
DISTRO=openbmc-openpower MACHINE=witherspoon-tacoma bitbake obmc-phosphor-image
```

or

```
source setup rainier
DISTRO=openbmc-openpower MACHINE=rainier bitbake obmc-phosphor-image
```